Is "Bich" really Latin for "generosity"?
In the song It’s Easy, M’kay, featured in South Park: Bigger, Longer & Uncut Soundtrack (1999), there is a line that goes:

Step three: with bitch, drop the 'T'
'Cause "Bich" is Latin for generosity!
(source)

I've many times attempted to look this up, but it doesn't seem to match. For example:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bich
https://translate.yandex.com/?lang=la-en&text=Bich&source_lang=la&target_lang=en
I also tried lowercase "bich". Same thing.
I always thought it was funny and clever that they found this out for the song, but apparently, they just made this "Latin" word up? Or am I missing something?

Uh, this is South Park we are talking about right, why would you expect this to be real lol. of course they made it up

I think there are NO words in Latin that end in "ch". Words from Greek or a Germanic language that do would have an ending such as -a or -us added, if they were adopted into Latin. I've spent a little time looking for something definitive about this, but there isn't much to find. This may actually be a obscure joke about the Latin language itself.

@Wastrel The Latin Bible generally affixes no endings to Hebrew names, so you have a few spellings like Enoch and Baruch... not really Latin words, though.

Indeed, bich is not Latin for "generosity".
It isn't a Latin word at all, and it doesn't even remotely look like one.
They just made it up.
I can't tell whether they were confused by a misleading source or whether they invented it themselves.

Definitely looks like a German word (but isn't one either).

@SebastianKoppehel we could offer "Bach" (creek) or "Buch" (book) instead.

Maybe because similar to bis, especially in the sense of encore where an audience would call "Bis! Bis!" to get the artist to (generously) play another number.
But that is more a French (Italian, Dutch, European?) thing, not sure fits for South Park / USA.
